# How do i cast an object to a List<Object[]> type?

Tags: java, object, casting

I have a situation where i get an Object as a return type and it needs to be casted to a `List<Object[]>` type. This looks easier then it seems though.

First of all when i try the following: `Object[] objectArray = (Object[])object;` i get the warning that the (Object[]) cast is redundant. Why on earth would this be redundant? An Object surely must be something different to an Object Array right? Well according to Intellij its secretly the same thing and i would appreciate it if someone could explain me why this is the case.

Because of the above described phenomenon i can't do this either:

```
Object[] objects = (Object[])callOutputs.getOutputParameterValue(entrySet.getValue());
List<Object[]> objectList = Arrays.asList(objects);
```

Despite casting the returntype explicitly to Object[], `Arrays.asList()` still treats it as an Object. Even though the variable type is `Object[]`.

Can someone explain how you should create a `List<Object[]>`  object?

EDIT: Here is the method declaration:

```
public abstract <T> T getOutputParameterValue(org.hibernate.procedure.ParameterRegistration<T> parameterRegistration)
```

Comment: Can you add the declaration of `getOutputParameterValue`?

Comment: @ernest_k there you go

Comment: Somehow I suspected the method was generic.

Comment: @ernest_k it doesn't matter whether the method would have returned a generic type or `Object` type explicitly, because of type erasure the return type would end up as Object in both cases.

Comment: What about explicitly casting return type of Arrays.asList? List<Object[]> objectList = (List<Object[]>) Arrays.asList(objects);

Comment: @Maurice Not sure what you mean. The compiler can indeed enforce type compatibility in this case even if the return type is a type variable.

Comment: Why are you doing ```Arrays.asList(Object[])``` to assign the result to ```List<Object[]>```? ```Arrays.asList(Object[])``` results in a list of ```Object```, not of ```Object[]```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `entrySet.getValue()` returns `ParameterRegistration<Object[]>` (otherwise there would be a compiler error). That being the case,

```
Object[] objects = (Object[])callOutputs.getOutputParameterValue(entrySet.getValue());
```

is casting `Object[]` to `Object[]`. `getOutputParameterValue()` returns the type of its input's type argument (The `T` in `ParameterRegistration<T>`), so the compiler can check that the return type is `Object[]` and you don't need to explicitly cast it.

The `Arrays.asList()` thing is a different story.

`Arrays.asList(Object[])` is expected to return `List<Object>`, because the method is declared to take an array of type `T`, and returns a `List<T>`.

If you want it to be a `List<Object[]>`, you can force it by adding a type witness

```
List<Object[]> objectList = Arrays.<Object[]>asList(objects);
```

This is needed only when you have a single argument (it wouldn't be needed if you had something like `Arrays.<Object[]>asList(objects, objects1, objects2)`)